# For which values of n does Improper Integral Converge

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

[image]

I'm really struggling on these, particularly part B.  I plugged in a bunch of different of values for the parameter p, and I simply cannot get the integral to converge.  Is it even possible, because I've tried many combinations already, unless I am just making a silly mistake.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first integral converges for all $n\ge0$ because the integrand $f $ is continuous on $[0,1)$, and as $x\to 1^-$ one has $f(x)=\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{(1+x)(1+x^2)}}\frac1{\sqrt {1-x}}\sim \frac12 \frac1{\sqrt{1-x}} $, so we conclude from the convergence of $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}} $.
Besides, for $-1 <n <0$ , as $x\to0^+$ we have $f(x)\sim 1/ x^{-n} $ therefore the integral converges also for these $n$, and diverges for smaller ones.

Looking at the second one similarly, for convergence we see that as $x\to1^+$ we need $q <1$ and as $x\to\infty $ we need $p>1$ OR $p=1, q>1$. It follows that $p>1>q.$

Comment: The first one only converges for $n > -1$. For $n \leqslant -1$ the integral diverges due to the presence of the $1/x^{-n}$ term which dominates as $x \to 0^+$.

Comment: @omegadot: I'm afraid you didn't read carefully.

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now. My apologies.

Comment: No worries. $ \ $